# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getCreationHelper()Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCreationHelper;

Tags: java, jasper-reports, nosuchmethoderror

Before I am using jasperreports-3.7.4 jar for downloading Jasper Reports in the form of Excel Format. Now I am trying to upgrade to jasperreports-6.3.1 jar. But it showing Error like "j**ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getCreationHelper()Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCreationHelper;**" while calling        **exporterXLS.exportReport()** method. I am using poi-3.6 jar also. Please provide solution to resolve this problem. Please find my code bellow.

```
    handleDataBase db=null;
try {

    OutputStream OutputStream = res.getOutputStream();
     db = new handleDataBase();
    Utility.comment("attra","before loading the Report "+new java.util.Date() + " - file name is "+reportFileName);
    Connection connObj = db.getConnection();
    //String jrPrint =JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jrxmlFile,params,connObj);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jrxmlFile, params, connObj);
    Utility.comment("attra","After loading the Report "+new java.util.Date()+ " - file name is "+reportFileName);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream    = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


    JRXlsExporter exporterXLS = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT,jasperPrint);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM,byteArrayOutputStream);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE); 
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE); 
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
    //****************************Newly added by Shubham***************************************
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER,Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,Boolean.FALSE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IMAGE_BORDER_FIX_ENABLED,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_FONT_SIZE_FIX_ENABLED,Boolean.TRUE);
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS,Boolean.FALSE);
    //***
    exporterXLS.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IGNORE_PAGE_MARGINS,Boolean.TRUE);
    //*****************************************************************************************
    exporterXLS.exportReport();//**Here I am getting above error**

     //To enable report to get  downloaded in IE on an https connection
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
    res.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","filename=\"" + reportFileName + "\";");
    res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    OutputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()); 
    OutputStream.flush();
    OutputStream.close();   

} catch (Exception e) {
    Utility.comment("attra","Exception inside generateReport "+e.getMessage());

}   finally{
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: You should use versions of 3rd party libraries as defined at JasperReports' *pom.xml*

Answer (score 1):

You may have to upgrade Apache POI to 3.8 or later. `getCreationHelper()` have been changed from:

```
public CreationHelper getCreationHelper() {
    return new HSSFCreationHelper(this);
}
```

to:

```
public HSSFCreationHelper getCreationHelper() {
    return new HSSFCreationHelper(this);
}
```

since 3.8.